# DDD: should entity method use repository for stored procedures (not CRUD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository, stored-procedures

Imagine you have a **Vehicle** entity in your domain model. Vehicle entity has **Reserve** method that put vehicle in "reserved" state and do another stuff. But Reserve method have to do some checking first to ensure that reservation could be done. This checking is done by legacy stored procedure that have to be called as a part of reservation process. Stored procedure call is encapsulated in repository method.

**The question:**
Should I pass repository as a parameter of domain entity method if method interacts with data storage? Are there any drawbacks of such a solution? Are there alternatives?

**The sample:**

```
class VehicleRepository: IVehicleRepository {
    public bool IsReserveAvailable() {
        // call stored proc here
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    public void Reserve (IVehicleRepository vehicleRepository) {
        bool isReserveAvailable = vehicleRepository.IsReserveAvailable();
        if (isReserveAvailable) {
            // do stuff ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind if checks are done by the stored procedure?

Comment: And what logic is done by the Reserve method. So far seems to me a violation of responsabilities allowing the vehicle to know how to make a reserve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Repositories from Domain](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166000/accessing-repositories-from-domain)

Comment: Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700918/5934037)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of having the Method on the vehicle class is that it matches your business language. "I want to reserve the vehicle please!"

The disadvantage is that whenever you have a vehicle, you have to also have the dependent service around in case you want  to reserve it.

If you can refactor it out of the sproc so that it is only a logic operation on the members of Vehicle great.

But if you can't, because the operation relies on information outside of the Vehicle, such as knowledge of all other vehicles, then you might want to consider a VehicleReservationService class which you pass the Vehicle object to.

After all, you are really only hiding the existence of this service with Vehicle.Reserve(IDependency repo). Sometimes the business language is wrong and needs to change,

Clarification:

No. You should not pass the repository. Either move code out of the db if it can be made a pure function of Vehicle. Or create a VehicleResevationService to deal wth reservations.

Sample:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public bool Reserve()
    {
        if(this.x && this.y)
        {
            this.Status = "reserved";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class VehicleReservationService
{
    public VehicleReservationService(IRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public bool Reserve(Vehicle v)
    {
        return repo.Reserve(v.Id, v.OtherParametersOfSproc);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to reserve the vehicle please!"... Do say it to the car or to someone else? The car doesn't know anything about the booking process...

Comment: I have added a clarification

Comment: I still miss something here. Probably, Vehicle repository should not perform business logic either. Don't you think that a cross-cutting conocept is missing? *Reservation* for example. It's a "bounded context" in its own rigth.

Comment: Well @Ewan give pretty explanatory answer. My only concern is that huge use of stored procedures will cause moving logic from entity to domain services. Domain model will tend to be more anemic that is considered by some developers (not me) as anti-pattern.

Comment: To reduce the anemic feeling, you could put `VehicleReservationService` into `Vehicle` class itself. This will make the service integral part of the entity, thus allow the service to access private fields and methods of it's parent entity. While at the same time being able to properly DI the service itself.

Comment: @euphoric I would not recommend that approach. I think the initial confusion was due to my equation of service and repository. essentially anything you inject implies that you have broken you bounded context in my view. Repo or servixe

Comment: How does bounded context come into question here? Both the entity, its repositories and services all exist in exactly the same bounded context. Bounded contexts are for DOMAIN separation, not TECHNICAL separation. Also, I think I heard somewhere that repository is special type of service. So I would not expect much separation between them.

Comment: @PhilippBocharov `huge use of stored procedures will cause moving logic from entity to domain services. Domain model will tend to be more anemic that is considered by some developers (not me) as anti-pattern.` well the model is still anemic if we consider that the logic is in the DB proc. Moving logic out of the model not necessarily makes the mode anemic. Placing the logic where It should be improves the code cohesion and the encapsulation of the different "boundaries" within the domain. IMO. We will move to services, logic that doesn't belongs explictly to a unique  "boundary".

Comment: we are somewhat limited in that we don't know what the sproc actually does. it might that _some_ of the logic is suitable for a class method. My guess though is that it operates on either other vehicles, 'is any other vehicle available?' or objects 'has a customer reserved this vehicle'. To my mind that means Vehicle isnt the right place for the Method, possibly if you pressed the business further you could get them to say 'a customer makes a reservation' or  'a vehicle **type** is reserved' or something which would give you a nice DDD/OOP name for your service

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally not in a group of people who think that `Entities` should not access `Repositories`. So to me, the answer to your question is "Yes, sure, go ahead."

But in case you don't want to do that, I would like to change Ewan's solution slightly.

```
// notice this is not general vehicle repository
public interface IVehicleReservationRepository
{
    bool IsReserveAvailable();
}

public class Vehicle
{
    // notice Reserve being private
    // should only be called when reservation can happen
    private void Reserve()
    {
        // do stuff ...
    }

    public class ReservationService
    {
        private IVehicleReservationRepository _vehicleReservationRepo;

        public ReservationService(IVehicleReservationRepository vehicleReservationRepo)
        {
            _vehicleReservationRepo = vehicleReservationRepo;
        }

        public void Reserve(Vehicle v)
        {
            bool isReserveAvailable = _vehicleReservationRepo.IsReserveAvailable();
            if (isReserveAvailable)
            {
                v.Reserve();
            }
        }

        public void ReserveAll(IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles)
        {
            // efficient reservation for multiple vehicles
            // doesn't need to call repository for every vehicle
        }
    }
}
```

By making the `RegistrationService` nested of `Vehicle`, it allows it to access it's private members. This is because making the service nested to the entity couples them together. So the service is integral part of the entity. It is still possible to use DI to create the `ReservationService` and having it separate like this makes it clear what operations make use of the repository service.

Another thing to point out is that instead of using generic `IVehicleRepository`, I created special `IVehicleReservationRepository`, that is only used in this use case. In the end, it might be implemented on `VehicleRepository`, but that is unrelated to this problem. Making interface specific for one use case is good usage of interface segregation principle and would make testing easier, as you don't need to worry about other methods present on full repository.

Last thing that came to my mind is scenario, where you might want to reserve multiple vehicles. If you had Reserve method on a Entity, you would have to call it on each vehicle, calling repository, and thus database, for every entity. But having separate service allows you to optimize this by calling repository once for multiple vehicles. As seen in `ReserveAll` method on the `ReservationService`.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate the benefits of allowing entities to meet their repositories? That reminds me to Active Record design pattern. Despite it's considered anti-pattern, I have found libs that implement it. So I'm missing the Pros. The cons I think are clear.

Comment: @Laiv The critical difference between Active Record and entity being able to access it's repository is that, with Active Record, it is not possible to structurally separate the implementation of repository (eg. the SQL commands) from the entity/record. But having a middle man, like an interface, does make that possible. So for example, unit testing of entities, in isolation from persistence technology, becomes possible. Which is, I think, main complain when using Active records.

Comment: ok. From the unit-testing standpoint, your approach is preferable. But what's the point of allowing entities to meet the DAL? Maybe I'm too oldschool or biased by too many years abstracting the model from everything else.

Comment: @Laiv Can you explain what you mean by DAL? Also, do you think domain should have abstraction of "collection of all existing entities" within itself?  If yes, how is this abstraction represented? If not, how would domain express behavior that works on all existing entities? And by all existing entities I mean for example "all current vehicles".

Comment: Ok, ok. I think I got your point now. Basically you are looking at the repository as the collection of the existing vehicles while I'm still looking at it as a DAO. But still, should a single entity to be aware of everyone else (should a vehicle to have access the collection?) I guess the answer is no, and that's why you suggested the interface segregation, in order to don't force vehicles to be aware of the collection itself. I'm right?

Comment: @Laiv This is simply question of interface segregation. In big majority of cases entity will not need access to collection of it's siblings, but I think there might be cases where, if whole entity depended on ability to query other entities or aggregate of those entities, then it is good design to give it reference to API that allows just that. Not giving it the API because of some dogmatic ideas of forbidding entities to access repositories is, I believe, wrong.

Comment: @Laiv In my example, there is specific interface only for querying reservation status and only the Reservation service depends it. This makes the cut on both sides. As only code handling reservation depends on API intended only for reservations. So yes, you are correct.

Comment: great. Thank you for remind me that repositories are still abstractions within the domain itself.